# prevent trigger fire from a future method

Tags: apex, trigger, class, future

I would like know if there is any global variable i can use to prevent trigger fire from a future method.

Like I can use

```
System.isBatch()
```

to prevent trigger fire from batch classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.isFuture will do what you're looking for. You can also use the [System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) class to determine if you're running in a scheduled context, batchable context, or queueable context.